# java: Hyphen '-' (a dash) is converted to special character (â€“) while reading cell value from excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, selenium, jxl

In my project I have to read values from excel sheet(testData.xls), store it in a variable(I have used string variable).And use this variable to make the xpath for corresponding field in web application.
Value stored in testData.xls is in "[Premium - Test 2] or [Premium - Run]" format.
But when this is stored in string variable it becomes 'Premium â€“ Test 2' or 'Premium â€“ Run'.

As the string variable is changing, xpath is changing and my test script fails.

Please let me know how can we fix this issue.

I am using jxl, Selenium WebDriver... in this project
Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Comment: How are you retrieving cell data? I tried with `String content = col1row1.getContents();` and it is giving proper value including hyphen.

Comment: Is it a hyphen or a dash, like en-dash or em-dash?

Comment: Facing same issue. Any solution to this?